# ifelse based on several conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
a <- c(26, 26, 156, 801, 143, 4, 455, 446, 447, 241, 461, 343, 359, 409, 241)
b <- c(26, 26, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
c <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
d <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 446, 447, NA, 461, NA, NA, NA, NA)

test <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

I'd like get a next vector `e`based on the values in `test$b`, `test$c` and `test$d`. I'm still used to the if-command in excel, therefore I tried this:

```
test$e <- ifelse(is.na(b)==TRUE, ifelse(is.na(c)==TRUE, ifelse(is.na(d)==TRUE)), test$a, NA)
```

and

```
test$e <- ifelse(is.na(b)==TRUE && is.na(c)==TRUE && is.na(d)==TRUE, test$a, NA)
```

Obviously that did not work. I'm sure this can't be too difficult, `test`should look like this afterwards:

```
    a  b  c   d   e
1   26 26 NA  NA  NA
2   26 26 NA  NA  NA
3  156 NA NA  NA  156
4  801 NA NA  NA  801
5  143 NA NA  NA  143
6    4 NA  4  NA  NA
7  455 NA NA  NA  455
8  446 NA NA 446  NA
9  447 NA NA 447  NA
10 241 NA NA  NA  241
11 461 NA NA 461  NA
12 343 NA NA  NA  343
13 359 NA NA  NA  359
14 409 NA NA  NA  409
15 241 NA NA  NA  241
```

What is the correct way to do this with `ifelse` and are there other (maybe more simple) ways?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the sing `&` that works as boolean and for vectors:

```
test$e <- with(test, ifelse(is.na(b) & is.na(c) & is.na(d), a, NA))
```

Note the difference between the `&&` and `&` operator: `a && b` is made for scalar boolean values and has a shortcut built in: If `a` already is false, `b` will not be evaluated at all. `a & b` on the other hand is guaranteed to evaluate `a` and `b` and works on vectors.

There are a lot of ways to make the selection you described. Richard Scrivens's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23406929/601303) is another possibility. As so often in R the best choice is a matter of style. Personally, right now I find the solution with the `&` the most appealing, as it is clear about what it does and does not require one of the more fancy functions. If, however, there are 10 but not three entries, I would definitely prefer another way.

Comment: Note that you don't need the ==TRUE part since is.na returns a logical value already.

Comment: @Dason, you were able to get the desired output from this answer?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Sorry, corrected the answer. As I wrote my answer the original question still was another version.

Comment: @Thilo: Sorry for the inconvenience. I corrected the question into the correct form.

Answer (score 2):

You are basically changing only those rows with three `NA` values, so we can use
 `sum(is.na(...)) == 3` in the `if` statement.

```
  ## this way is a bit slower than using rowSums()
> test$e <- ifelse(apply(test, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) == 3, test$a, NA)
```

As suggested by flodel, `rowSums` would probably be a better, faster route.

```
> test$e <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(test[c("b", "c", "d")])) == 3, test$a, NA)
> test
##      a  b  c   d   e
## 1   26 26 NA  NA  NA
## 2   26 26 NA  NA  NA
## 3  156 NA NA  NA 156
## 4  801 NA NA  NA 801
## 5  143 NA NA  NA 143
## 6    4 NA  4  NA  NA
## 7  455 NA NA  NA 455
## 8  446 NA NA 446  NA
## 9  447 NA NA 447  NA
## 10 241 NA NA  NA 241
## 11 461 NA NA 461  NA
## 12 343 NA NA  NA 343
## 13 359 NA NA  NA 359
## 14 409 NA NA  NA 409
## 15 241 NA NA  NA 241
```

Comment: you should also replace `test` with `test[c("b", "c", "d")]` in yours. (these assumptions you are making about the data are dangerous. try running the code twice for example.)